# how to take many inputs from user and how to display it

Tags: ruby

I have gone through some of your answer regarding my question but u have mentioned only for single input but I need it for multiple inputs how can I try this.
the code of my controller is like this

```
def there
  @data = params[:text1]
end
```

for reading one more input can i include

```
def there
  @data =params[:text1]
end
```

HTML

```
<form action = "/hello1/there1" > Please enter your name. <br> 
  <input type="text" name="text1"><br><br> 
  enter your detail <br> 
  <input type="string" detail="text2"> <br> <br> 
  <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: It appears that some context is missing.

Comment: <form action = "/hello1/there1" >
       Please enter your name.
       <br>
       <input type="text" name="text1"><br><br>
       enter your detail
       <br>
       <input type="string" detail="text2">
       <br>
       <br>
       <input type="submit"/>
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>   view page look like this

Comment: @harshithamg Please edit the question to add more details (unreadable as a comment).

Comment: how can i read multiple inputs ,and to save those inputs and should be displsay it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you submit a form in Rails, it submits a hash of `params`. You can access the value by it's key e.g. below:

```
def there
  @data = params[:text1]
  @otherdata = params[:text2]
end
```

Also your form structure is wrong. Below is the correct markup:

```
<form action = "/hello1/there" > Please enter your name. <br> 
  <input type="text" name="text1"><br><br> 
  enter your detail <br> 
  <input type="text" name="text2"> <br> <br> 
  <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: yeh wow it worked thank you yar..

Comment: If it's correct answer, please mark it so and you're welcome!